# Why don't my pieces shuffle on the client's end?

Tags: unity, networking, mirror-networking

In my game there is a 'Shuffle()' function that both clients and the host can access that shuffles pieces around on a board:

```
[Command(requiresAuthority = false)]
public void Shuffle()
{
    RefreshPieceList();
    randPos = piecePos;
    randRot = pieceRot;

    foreach (Transform child in transform)
    {
        if (child.CompareTag("FoodPiece"))
        {
            newRandRot = randRot[Random.Range(0, randRot.Count - 1)];
            newRandPos = randPos[Random.Range(0, randPos.Count - 1)];
            child.position = newRandPos;
            child.rotation = newRandRot;
            randPos.Remove(newRandPos);
            randRot.Remove(newRandRot);

            foreach (Transform grandchild in child) 
            {
                Destroy(grandchild.gameObject);
                NetworkServer.Destroy(grandchild.gameObject);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So the idea is that the shuffle function shuffles piece positions/rotations and the NetworkTransformChild component would synchronize the new positions onto the clients.

However, when I run the shuffle function on either the client or the host, the host's pieces are all shuffled correctly while the client's haven't changed at all.

Before Shuffling:
[image]
After Shuffling:
[image]

To keep positions of the pieces consistent between server and client I set the WorldPositionStays as true when declaring their parents.
[image]

But still, the positions of pieces after shuffling still isn't the same. Why?

Comment: In general, reference types are not passed as arguments to rpc, because their memory addresses are different on different physical machines. You should number each object on the server, passing their id rather than Transform. And you seem to be doing the same thing in two ways at the same time. You should always do something in only one way at the same time.

Comment: The parameter types that can be serialized are listed [here](https://docs-multiplayer.unity3d.com/netcode/current/advanced-topics/serialization/serialization-intro), and they are also the parameter types that can be passed to rpc.

Comment: What do you mean by doing the same thing in two ways at the same time? I'm sending a command to the server to shuffle the pieces positions around. The only thing the client is receiving is the new coordinates.

Comment: Also the data types I am using, quaternion and Vector3, are listed as being serialized out of the box...  [link](https://docs-multiplayer.unity3d.com/netcode/current/advanced-topics/serialization/unity-primitives)

Comment: `Transform` is a not serializable type. You can manually assign an id to the object on the server, or use [networkobject](https://docs-multiplayer.unity3d.com/netcode/current/advanced-topics/serialization/networkobject-serialization).

Comment: `Network Transform Child` is from [mirror](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/network/mirror-129321). and `Rpc` in used is from [multiplayer](https://docs-multiplayer.unity3d.com/). They are trying to do the same thing: sync location between client and server. You can try to choose one of them instead of mixing them.

Comment: I did fix the problem of using both Rpc and NTC by removing the ClientRpc function all together, as the NTC component would synchronize position of pieces once they were changed on the server. However, now there is a new problem that the pieces aren't shuffling on the client's end at all. More details on the edited post above.